# How can I set a button as disabled after the 15s has passed without any interaction?? Discord v14

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const config = require('../../botconfig');

module.exports = {
name: 'invite',
description: 'Crimson and Server invites',
run: async (client, interaction, args) => {
   try {
   const inviteEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setDescription('**__Invite • Support__**\n\n<a:Arrow:735141069033046106> Want to invite Crimson to your server? Feel free to click on the **"Invite"** button.\n\n<a:Arrow:735141069033046106> Need additional help with Crimson? Come join us in our humble abode by clicking on the **"Support"** button.')
      .setColor('#EE1C25')
      .setFooter({ text: `Command Requested by: ${interaction.user.tag}`, iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL() })
      .setTimestamp()
      .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL());

   let botInvite = new ButtonBuilder()
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Link)
      .setURL(`https://discord.com/`)
      .setLabel('Invite');

   let support = new ButtonBuilder()
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Link)
      .setURL('https://discord.gg/')
      .setLabel('Support');
    
   let del = new ButtonBuilder()
      .setLabel(`Close`)
      .setCustomId(`delete`)
      .setEmoji(`❌`)
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);

   const inviteMsg = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [inviteEmbed], components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(botInvite, support, del)], fetchReply: true });

   const collector = inviteMsg.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: ComponentType.Button, time: 15000 });

   collector.on('collect', async i => {
      if (i.user.id === interaction.user.id) {
        console.log(`${i.user.tag} clicked on the ${i.customId} button.`);
      } else {
        await i.reply({ content: `This button is not for you!`, ephemeral: true });
      }

      if (i.id === 'delete') {
         inviteMsg.delete();
         interaction.delete();
     await i.reply.defer();
      }
   });
   
   collector.on('end', collected => {
      console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} interactions.`);
   });

   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
     return interaction.reply(`\`${err}\`.`);
   }
  }
};
```

I’ve been trying to mess around with it to see if i can but I’m running out of options to try

I don’t know if I can do the same thing as the embed and set it as disabled through the components thing but not sure if that’s the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily by disabling the buttons once your collector ends.

```
collector.on('end', collected => {
  botInvite.setDisabled(true);
  support.setDisabled(true);
  del.setDisabled(true);

  // edit the message with the components disabled
  inviteMsg.edit({embeds: [inviteEmbed], components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(botInvite, support, del)]});

  console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} interactions.`);
});
```

If you have multiple buttons that need to be disabled, this can get a little annoying to add in your code.

What you can do is creating a row with your components, adding it to your message, and then looping through the buttons.

```
const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(botInvite, support, del);

const inviteMsg = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [inviteEmbed], components: [row], fetchReply: true });

// when your collector ends:

collector.on('end', collected => {
  row.components.forEach(c => c.setDisabled(true));

  // edit message
  inviteMsg.edit({embeds: [inviteEmbed], components: [row]});
  console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} interactions.`);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it reset the 15 seconds after the button is clicked so it doesn’t disable while trying to be interacted with?

Comment: yeah, just add `idle: amount` instead of `time: amount` in your collector.
 `const collector = inviteMsg.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: ComponentType.Button, idle: 15000 });`